# Emberjs: How to refresh parent template after model create

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an app that has the following code:

Routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('gradebooks', function() {
    this.resource('gradebook', { path: ':gradebook_id' });
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('gradebooks');
  }
})

App.GradebooksRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    Em.$.getJSON('/data/gradebooks/get', function(data) {
      controller.set('model', data);
    });
  }
});

App.GradebookRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var id = params.gradebook_id;
    return Em.$.getJSON('/data/gradebooks/get/' + id);
  }
})
```

Controllers:

```
App.GradebooksController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  isActive: false,
  actions: {
    createGradebook: function(newTitle) {
      var self = this;
      if(newTitle.trim()) {
        Em.$.get('/data/gradebooks/add/' + newTitle, {}, function(json) {
          Em.$('#create-gradebook-modal').modal('hide').find('input').val('');
          self.transitionToRoute('gradebook', json.id);
        }, 'json');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Templates (gradebooks.hbs):

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create-gradebook-modal">
      <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
      Create Gradebook
    </button>
  </div>

  <ul>
    {{#each}}

    <li {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>
      {{#link-to "gradebook" _id}}
        {{title}}
      {{/link-to}}
    </li>

    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Templates (gradebook.hbs):

```
<h1>{{title}} <small>{{_id}}</small></h1>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Rename</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Trash</button>
</div>
```

What I'm having trouble with is under the `GradebooksController.actions.createGradebook`, I send a request to create the model and then I transition to the gradebook I just created. The creation and transition works just fine, but I want the sidebar `(gradebooks.hbs)` to show the newly created gradebook.

I think it has something to do with updating the model in the `GradebooksRoute`. How can I make it fetch for the models from the server again after creating a gradebook.

Comment: after creating the gradebook, push it to Gradebooks content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on @fanta's comment, you'll want to do something like this:

```
App.GradebooksController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  isActive: false,
  actions: {
    createGradebook: function(newTitle) {
      var self = this;
      if(newTitle.trim()) {
        var gradebook = Em.$.getJSON('/data/gradebooks/add/' + newTitle, {}, function(json) {
          Em.$('#create-gradebook-modal').modal('hide').find('input').val('');
          self.transitionToRoute('gradebook', json.id);
        }, 'json');
        self.get('content').pushObject(gradebook);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Works great except for some minor edits. `this.get('content').pushObject(gradebook);` needs to be `self.get...` and inside the `getJSON` callback.